# Scope Issue with Phaser - Using sound

Tags: audio, scope, phaser-framework

I am not able to stay in scope when working inside a function.  What is the best method to reference the right scope to access the soundManager?

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'game' of undefined**

on this line `console.log('SCOPE: ' +  MyGame.Game.sound.mute);`

```
$(".audiotoggle").click(function() {
            if (MyApp1.gameMuted === false) {
                MyApp1.gameMuted = true; //(angular vars)
                console.log('MUTE: TRUE (audiotoggle * TRIGGER)');
                audtioToggleFunc();
            } else {
                MyApp1.gameMuted = false; //(angular vars)
                console.log('MUTE: FALSE (audiotoggle * TRIGGER)');
                audtioToggleFunc();
            }
        });

        var audtioToggleFunc = function () {
            console.log('SCOPE: ' +  MyGame.Game.sound.mute);
            console.log('AUDIO TOGGLE');
            if (MyApp1.gameMuted === true) {
                MyGame.Game.sound.mute = false;
                console.log('MUTE: FALSE (audiotoggle * Function)');
            } else {
                MyGame.Game.sound.mute = true;
                console.log('MUTE: TRUE (audiotoggle * Function)');
            }
        };
        audtioToggleFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is rather a jquery question. You should use:

```
$(".audiotoggle").click(
    $.proxy(function () {
        //your listener code
    }, this)
);
```